# Slickgrid scrollRowIntoView is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

Below is the code I have written to use scrollRowIntoView.  I am using the resizer as I purposely want the grid to be the length of the browser window.  Eventually I will get the record I want to scroll from the URL, but for now I have just hard coded a number as an example although in the code you can see I have a getUrlVars function.  It seems to be truncating rows from the grid instead of scrolling to the row as expected.  You can just paste this code and into a html file and see the results.  Any help really appreciated as I am novice with this stuff.  Best, Dave

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Player Summary</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/examples.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/css/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<style>
</style>

<body>
    <div style="position:relative">
        <div style="width:1100px;">
            <div class="grid-header" style="width:100%">
                <label>August 18th Summary</label>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div id="myGrid"></div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/lib/jquery.event.drag-2.3.0.js"></script>
        <script src="http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.core.js"></script>
        <script src="http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.grid.js"></script>
        <script src="http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/slick.dataview.js"></script>
        <script src="http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/plugins/slick.resizer.js"></script>

        <script>
            var columns = [
                { id: "table", name: "Table", field: "table", sortable: true, minWidth: 50 },
                { id: "player", name: "Player", field: "player", sortable: true, minWidth: 50 },
                { id: "hand", name: "Hand", field: "hand", sortable: true, minWidth: 42 },
            ];

            var options = {
                enableCellNavigation: true,
                enableColumnReorder: true,
                multiColumnSort: true,
                //autoHeight: true, 
            };

            var data = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                data[i] = {
                    table: "Table1",
                    player: "AnyName",
                    hand: i
                };
            }

            function getUrlVars() {
                var vars = {};
                var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function (m, key, value) {
                    vars[key] = value;
                });
                return vars;
            }

            var scrolltoHand = getUrlVars()["hand"];

            var grid;
            var dataView;

            var data = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                data[i] = {
                    table: "Table1",
                    player: "AnyName",
                    hand: i
                };
            }

            $(function () {
            dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView()
            //grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
            grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, columns, options);

            // wire up model events to drive the grid
            //dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
            //    grid.updateRowCount();
            //    grid.render();
            //});

            //dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
            //    grid.invalidateRows(args.rows);
            //    grid.render();
            //});            
            // initialize the model after all the events have been hooked up
            dataView.beginUpdate();
            dataView.setItems(data, "hand");
            dataView.endUpdate();  
            grid.scrollRowIntoView(48);     

            // create the Resizer plugin
            // you need to provide a DOM element container for the plugin to calculate available space
            resizer = new Slick.Plugins.Resizer({
                container: '.container', // DOM element selector, can be an ID or a class name

                // optionally define some padding and dimensions
                rightPadding: 5,    // defaults to 0
                bottomPadding: 10,  // defaults to 20
                minHeight: 150,     // defaults to 180
                minWidth: 250,      // defaults to 300
            },
            );
            grid.registerPlugin(resizer);
        })
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scrollRowIntoView` requires a valid grid row index and it must be a number, if you try to scroll into an index that doesn't exist (outside the dataset length) it will probably not work either.

But I think what you're missing in your code is `grid.init()` which should be just before the `dataView.beginUpdate();`, you can see it in this [Example](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/examples/example-checkbox-header-row.html#L231)

```js
grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, columns, options);

grid.init(); // <<--this line

dataView.beginUpdate();
dataView.setItems(data);
dataView.endUpdate();
```

Comment: Thank you, I changed three things, I added id as a property to data, added the grid.init() and uncommented the dataview events.  This made it work although the top row is always one higher than the specified number.  I just subtract one.  Another question, if the row specified is on the last page it will not scroll to the top.  Is it possible to do this?  I guess I could add a bunch of blank rows at the end, but hoping for something more elegant.  Many thanks.

Comment: I rarely use the scroll to row and when I do I don't look at the paging but if you look at the function signature `scrollRowIntoView(row, doPaging)` you might want to try that 2nd argument, it seems to be related to the paging so... I often refer to the core directly to get answers, the code can reveal a lot ;)